# Error when trying to display an image saved in a computer file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am developing an application which allows me to bring some files saved from another server for that I have a code made in Asp.net which I consume with Javascript to bring the image, but when I get the image to show it, the following generates me error, Not allowed to load local resource: file: /// C: /Users/usuario/Desktop/imagenes/prfil/descarga.png, but when I copy the same link in the browser if it brings me the image:
This is my code .net:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string nombreArchivo)
{
    string directorio = "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\imagenes\"
    string ruta = directorio + nombreArchivo;
    if (File.Exists(ruta))
    {
        var result = new
        {
            imagen = ruta.Replace('\\', '/')
        }
        return Ok(result);
    }
    else
    {
        var result = new
        {
            imagen = "No existe la imagen"
        }
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

And this my code JavaScript:

```
const file = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:64108/api/Archivos/?nombreArchivo=perfil/descarga.png`);
    const datos = await res.json();

    foto.style.backgroundImage = `url('${datos.imagen}')`;
};
```

Comment: What value did you assign to the variable `directorio`?

Comment: @SalihKavaf I already added the value to the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers use the local `file://` protocol to load local files, which is only allowed for local calls. Same thing with HTTP protocol; it won't work to use this protocol followed by the full path of a local file. Yet, you have at least two options here. You either provide a public folder within your application's root directory, where you can access the file using a relative URI, which is the safer way of doing it.
Another possible approach is to return a file instead of a path. For this one, you may do something like this:

**Javascript**

```js
let url = "http://localhost:64108/api/Archivos/?nombreArchivo=perfil/descarga.png";
let init = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'image/png'
    }
};

fetch(url, init)
    .then(function (res) {
        // ...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // ...
    });
```

**C#**

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Get(string nombreArchivo)
{
    string directorio = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\imagenes\\";
    string ruta = directorio + nombreArchivo;

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(ruta))
        return File(path, Request.Headers["Accept"]); // We've already set this to "image/png" in the javascript part

    else return BadRequest("No existe la imagen");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it was a great help, I did not know about the local files, thanks for that explanation

Comment: Happy to help, my friend :)